# Error Running ASP.NET Application in Programmatically Created Virtual Directory in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7

I use the following code to configure add a virtual directory to my Default Web Site of the IIS 7 server.

```
            ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
            iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications.Add("/myVirtualDirectory", @"C:\Users\zee\Documents\Jumbo\CI\TestSite");
            iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Start();
            iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

The virtual directory gets created successfully, but there is a problem in running it. When the ASP site that resides in

> "C:\Users\zee\Documents\Jumbo\CI\TestSite"

is built using .NET 3.5 I get the following error...

[image]

But when I build this site using .NET 2.0, this error does not popup and the site runs without a problem.

Also, when I manually configure this virtual directory and run the site build on .NET 3.5, it still runs without an issue.

I checked my web.config file but there is no such duplicate.

So I assume that the problem occurs only when I programmatically configure the Virtual Directory.

What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with **web.config** inheritance. You are creating a virtual directory under Default Web Site - check on it's web.config (and override). Your Default Web Site might also be set to ASP.Net 2.0 (by default) along with it's settings.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Why would the default web site being set to ASP.NET 2.0 be a problem ?

Comment: Web.config settings are "propagated" down to your _virtual directories_ ([children](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx)) so you'll have to override them in the respective virtual apps.